# Compute and evaluate function of a function and keep the result a function

Tags: function-construction, evaluation, functional-style

Let's assume I have a various functions for signal amplitudes, e.g. `pulse[t_] = Sech[t]^2` and `pulse2[t_]L = Exp[-2t^2]`.

What I'd like to have is a general function the computes different forms of autocorrelation-like responses, let's take the autocorrelation as example. The result should be a function of time. So the autocorrelation should take a function as argument and return a function: `ac[pulse2] = 1/2 E^-#^2 Sqrt[\[Pi]]`

An easy solution but something I don't want is:

```
ac1[fct_] := ac1[fct] = Convolve[fct[\[Tau]], fct[\[Tau]], \[Tau], t]
```

resp.

```
ac2[fct_] :=  ac2[fct] = Integrate[fct[\[Tau]]*fct[\[Tau] - t], {\[Tau], -Infinity, Infinity}, Assumptions -> {Element[{t}, Reals]}]
```

The problem is that it returns an expression dependent on t and not a function.

My approach was something like

```
ac3[fct_] :=  ac3[fct] = Convolve[fct[\[Tau]], fct[\[Tau]], \[Tau], t] /. {t -> #} &
```

(`ac4` accordingly with `ac2`) but this won't evaluate the autocorrelation yet: `ac3[pulse2]=Convolve[pulse2[\[Tau]], pulse2[\[Tau]], \[Tau], t] /. {t -> #1} &`

So how can I make Mathematica evaluate the whole autocorrelation first (using `t`) and then replace `t` with `#` to get a function? I use version 11.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you want is to work with `Function` expressions for everything that represents a mathematical function. Here is how I would do what I think you intend:

First I would define `pulse` as a value holding a `Function` expression, this is not strictly necessary for the rest to work but makes more clear that you are going to pass this around:

```
ClearAll[pulse];
pulse = Function[t, Sech[t]^2];
```

The definition of `ac1` becomes slightly more complicated than before:

```
ac1[f_] := Module[{tau},
  Function[t, Evaluate[Convolve[f[tau], f[tau], tau, t]]]
]
```

You want to evaluate the `Convolve` and then turn the expression of the result into a function. As `Function` has the attribute `HoldAll` we need to explicitly evaluate its second argument, there are other ways to achieve the same thing which you can find on this site. I also localized the `tau` to keep the code working when the global symbol `tau` would have values (for `t` the scoping of `Function` does the job). Again there would be other possibilities to achieve the same thing. The result is again a `Function` expression which you can evaluate for a given argument or pass around as desired. It can be used just as a function defined by downvalues in almost every case, e.g.:

```
 response = ac1[pulse];
 Plot[response[t],{t,0.1,5}]
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation about `Function`. Inside the module (good point!), one can also use the shorthand `ac1[f_] := Evaluate[Convolve[f[tau], f[tau], tau, #]] &`, but I didn't manage to get the correct behaviour when trying around. Calling `Function` makes the behaviour more obvious.

Comment: @riddleculous: You might want to wait a bit before accepting my answer, there are probably other interesting answers. Just in case you are not aware of it: `#&` is only a shortcut for `Function[#]` (which is again a special case for `Function[x,x]`). If you look at the FullForm you will see that the two are internally the same thing.